# Read JSON questions file - JAVA game

Tags: arrays, json, object, readfile

I have the following JSON file with questions and answer options.
And the code I used trying to print the questions.

```js
{
  "GameName": "millionaire game",
  "level": 1,
  "questions": [
    {
      "question1": "What is the minimum of players in a footbal game?",
      "options1": [
        8,
        10,
        9,
        7
      ],
      "answer1": "7"
    },
    {
      "question2": "Who scored maximum goal footbal game?",
      "options2": [
        "Jhon",
        "Pitty",
        "Richard",
        "Mike"
      ],
      "answer2": "Mike"
    },
    {
      "question3": "What is the maximum of players in a footbal game?",
      "options3": [
        8,
        10,
        9,
        7
      ],
      "answer3": "7"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import org.json.*;

public class readJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {

        String first = "jsonPerguntas2.json";

        try {
            String content = new String((Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(first))));     
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(content);
            JSONArray firstQuestion = o.getJSONArray("question1");

            //System.out.println(conteudo);

            for (int i=0; i<firstQuestion.length(); i++){
                System.out.println(firstQuestion.get(i));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }  
    }  
}
```

I have this code to read the file. But it always return the same error:

```js
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["question1"] not found.
 at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:454)
 at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:535)
 at TrabPraticoJava.TesteLerJson.main(TesteLerJson.java:37)
C:\Users\José Dias\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TrabPraticoJava\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1341: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\José Dias\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TrabPraticoJava\nbproject\build-impl.xml:936: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

If I change the line `JSONArray firstQuestion = o.getJSONArray("question1");`  to `JSONArray firstQuestion = o.getJSONArray("questions");` it actually prints the all file but I want to print the questions separately.

Can someone help me out? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONArray questions = o.getJSONArray("questions");
  for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject question = recs.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(question.getInt("question"+i+1));
  }
```